# Regex rule optional matching characters set in a specific point

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm working with regex on PRCE2 environment.

In my switch logs I have to capture a text string that I'm capturing as `"message"` and that is located in a specific position. The focus point is that it is always preceded by a set of characters ending with `:` but, after them, I can have or not some addictional characters ending with `;` and I must be able to skip them.

Let me explain with my current regex and some log samples.

We can say that I have 3 chances:

```
 1. (s)[18014]:Recorded command information.
 2. (l):User logged out.
 3. (s)[18014]:CID=0x11aa2222;The user succeeded in logging out of XXX.
```

My current regex is:

```
\(\w+\)\[*\d*\]*\:(?<message>[^\[]+?\.)
```

that works for case 1 and 2 because:

- capture the fact that we always have a (, a literal character and a ) with `\(\w+\)`
- capture, as in case 2, if after that we have a [, a number and a ] with `\[*\d*\]*`
- in every case the following characters are `:` and I capture it with `\:`
- The message is captured, and named, with `(?<message>[^\[]+?\.)` that must avoid the capturing action if, after `:`, I have a `[`. The capture stops when when I get a `.`

My problem is: after the `:` I can have the case 3; it always begin with `CID=<exadecimal expression>;` but it is not only limited to this. After it, I can have other expression always ended by `;` So we can say that I can have, for case 3, `CID=<hex expression><other numeric and literal characters>;`.
With current regex, of course, the `CIDR` part is included in the message. I must avoid it; if the `CIDR` part is present, the message capture must start after the `;` that end it.

So, we can summarize that:
IF after the `:` we have no CIDR word, starts capturing; ELSE, avoid capturing until `;` and start the job after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern will match the right part of your test strings.
We look for either a `:` not followed by CID `?!CID` or a `;`. We then capture what follows.

```
((:(?!CID))|;)(.*)
```

see https://regex101.com/r/JRB4Rq/1

Answer (score 0):

You could write the pattern as:

```
\(\w+\)(?:\[\d+\])?:(?:CID=[^;]*;)?(?<message>[^.]+\.)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(\w+\)` Match 1+ word chars between parenthesis
- `(?:\[\d+\])?` Optionally match 1+ digits between square brackets
- `:` Match the colon (you don't have to escape it)
- `(?:CID=[^;]*;)?` Optionally match the CID= part till the first semicolon
- `(?<message>[^.]+\.)` Group *message*, match 1+ chars other than `.` and then match the `.`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UGwNQ5/1).